# ReferenceError: function is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

Hello i am newbie to javascript and angularjs,I have made a function in my comtroller for opening a website,and i am calling that function on "onclick" of a button",I am getting **ReferenceError: openWebsite is not defined** when i am trying to do this,my code is as below,Please help me to solve this,thanks in advance.

**controller**

```
     app.controller('listingdetailController', function ($http, $scope, $compile, $filter, $sce) {

        var Catid = '1';
        var SearchTxt = 'cay';
        var url = encodeURI("http://www.yahoo.com");


        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:  API_HOST+'/webservice/listingdetail',
            headers:
                    {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'caymanauth': caymanauth
                    },
            data: "&Catid=" + Catid + "&SearchTxt=" + SearchTxt,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }).success(function (data)
        {

            var i;
            var Content = ' ';
            for (i = 0; i<data['Details'].length; i++)
            {
                if (Content === ' ')
                {
                    Content =

 '<div class="app-page-photo">'+   
      '<div class="app-hero">'+
        '<ul class="image ng-scope" rn-carousel="">'+

          '<li style="display: inline-block; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">'+
             '<div class="bgimage" ng-style="{background-image: url("images/gallery/01.png")}" style="background-image: url("images/gallery/01.png");">'+
             '</div>'+
          '</li>'+
          '<li style="display: inline-block; transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px);">'+
             '<div class="bgimage" ng-style="{background-image: url("images/gallery/02.png")}" style="background-image: url("images/gallery/02.png");">'+
             '</div>'+
          '</li>'+
          '<li style="display: inline-block; transform: translate3d(200%, 0px, 0px);">'+
             '<div class="bgimage" ng-style="{background-image: url("images/gallery/03.png")}" style="background-image: url("images/gallery/03.png");">'+
             '</div>'+
          '</li>'+
        '</ul>'+ 
       ' </div>'+
      '</div>'+


      '<ons-list class="app-photo-buttons list ons-list-inner">'+
         '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner list__item--action-buttons" modifier="action-buttons">'+
            '<ons-row class="action row ons-row-inner">'+

              '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner">'+ 
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-android-call fa-lg" icon="ion-android-call">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Phone</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+


             '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner" onclick="sendEmail(message.Email, message.subject, message.body)";>'+ 
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-ios-email fa-lg" icon="ion-ios-email">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Email</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+



              '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner">'+ 
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-earth fa-lg" icon="ion-earth">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Website</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+


              '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner">'+ 
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-android-share-alt fa-lg" icon="ion-android-share-alt">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Share</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+       
            '</ons-row>'+
        '</ons-list-item>'+
      '</ons-list>'+                      

         '<ons-list style="border-top: none;">' +
         '<ons-list-item>' +
         '<ons-row class="detail-row">' +
         '<ons-col style="-webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px ; width=30px">' +
         '<ons-icon icon="fa-map-marker" fixed-width="true">' + '</ons-icon>' +
         '</ons-col>' +
          '<ons-col>' +

          '<div class="desc">'+
          '<ons-icon class="ons-icon fa-map-marker fa fa-lg" fixed-width="true" icon="fa-map-marker">'+
          '</ons-icon>'
          + data['Details'][i]['varCityName']+
          '</div>'+
          '</ons-col>' +
          '</ons-row>' +
          '</ons-list-item>' + '<br>' +


          '<ons-list-item>' +
          '<ons-row class="detail-row">' +
          '<ons-col style="-webkit-box-flex: 0 flex: 0 0 30px max-width: 30px width=30px">' +
          '<ons-icon icon="ion-home" fixed-width="true">'+'</ons-icon>'+
          '</ons-col>' +                          

          '<ons-col>' +
          '<div class="desc">'+
          '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-home fa-lg" fixed-width="true" icon="ion-home">'+
          '</ons-icon>'+ data['Details'][i]['varPhysicalAddress'] + 
          '</div>' +
          '</ons-col> ' +
          '</ons-row>' +
          '</ons-list-item>' + 
          '<br>' +


          '<ons-list-item>' +
          '<ons-row class="detail-row">' +
          '<ons-col style="-webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px ; width=30px">' +
              '<ons-icon icon="ion-soup-can" fixed-width="true">' + '</ons-icon>' +
            '</ons-col>' +

             '<ons-col>' +
            '<div class=desc>'+'<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-soup-can fa-lg" fixed-width="true" icon="ion-soup-can">'+
            '</ons-icon>'
            + data['Details'][i]['varPOBOXAddress']+
            '</div>'+
            '</ons-col>'+
            '</ons-row>'+
             '</ons-list-item>'+
             '</ons-list>'+
             '<div class=caw-botton>'+
            '<ons-row class="row ons-row-inner">'+ 
                '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("book-page.html");>'+
                 '<div style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.6); padding: 12px 0; background: #0ad046; color: #FFF;">'+
                   '<i class="ion-compose">'+'</i>Book Now</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+
               '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("book-page.html");>'+
                   '<div style="padding: 12px 0; background: #cccccc; color: #FFF;">'+
                  '<i class="ion-edit">'+
                  '</i>Write a Review</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+
             '</ons-row>'+
                ' </div>';

                }

                else
                {


   '<div class="app-page-photo">'+   
      '<div class="app-hero">'+
        '<ul class="image ng-scope" rn-carousel="">'+

          '<li style="display: inline-block; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">'+
             '<div class="bgimage" ng-style="{background-image: url("images/gallery/01.png")}" style="background-image: url("images/gallery/01.png");">'+
             '</div>'+
          '</li>'+
          '<li style="display: inline-block; transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px);">'+
             '<div class="bgimage" ng-style="{background-image: url("images/gallery/02.png")}" style="background-image: url("images/gallery/02.png");">'+
             '</div>'+
          '</li>'+
          '<li style="display: inline-block; transform: translate3d(200%, 0px, 0px);">'+
             '<div class="bgimage" ng-style="{background-image: url("images/gallery/03.png")}" style="background-image: url("images/gallery/03.png");">'+
             '</div>'+
          '</li>'+
        '</ul>'+ 
       ' </div>'+
      '</div>'+


      '<ons-list class="app-photo-buttons list ons-list-inner">'+
         '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner list__item--action-buttons" modifier="action-buttons">'+
            '<ons-row class="action row ons-row-inner">'+

              '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner">'+ 
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-android-call fa-lg" icon="ion-android-call">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Phone</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+


              '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner">'+ 
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-ios-email fa-lg" icon="ion-ios-email">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Email</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+



               '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner" onclick="sendEmail(message.Email, message.subject, message.body)";>'+
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-earth fa-lg" icon="ion-earth">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Website</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+


              '<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner">'+ 
              '<div style="border-right: 1px solid #ffc22f; padding: 10px 0;">'+
              '<div class="action-icon">'+
              '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-android-share-alt fa-lg" icon="ion-android-share-alt">'+
              '</ons-icon>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<div class="action-label">Share</div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+       
            '</ons-row>'+
        '</ons-list-item>'+
      '</ons-list>'+                      





        '<ons-list style="border-top: none;">' +
         '<ons-list-item>' +
         '<ons-row class="detail-row">' +
         '<ons-col style="-webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px ; width=30px">' +
         '<ons-icon icon="fa-map-marker" fixed-width="true">' + '</ons-icon>' +
         '</ons-col>' +
          '<ons-col>' +

          '<div class="desc">'+
          '<ons-icon class="ons-icon fa-map-marker fa fa-lg" fixed-width="true" icon="fa-map-marker">'+
          '</ons-icon>'
          + data['Details'][i]['varCityName']+
          '</div>'+
          '</ons-col>' +
          '</ons-row>' +
          '</ons-list-item>' + '<br>' +


          '<ons-list-item>' +
          '<ons-row class="detail-row">' +
          '<ons-col style="-webkit-box-flex: 0 flex: 0 0 30px max-width: 30px width=30px">' +
          '<ons-icon icon="ion-home" fixed-width="true">'+'</ons-icon>'+
          '</ons-col>' +


          '<ons-col>' +
          '<div class="desc">'+
          '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-home fa-lg" fixed-width="true" icon="ion-home">'+
          '</ons-icon>'+ data['Details'][i]['varPhysicalAddress'] + 
          '</div>' +
          '</ons-col> ' +
          '</ons-row>' +

          '</ons-list-item>' + 
          '<br>' +


          '<ons-list-item>' +
          '<ons-row class="detail-row">' +
          '<ons-col style="-webkit-box-flex: 0; flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px ; width=30px">' +
              '<ons-icon icon="ion-soup-can" fixed-width="true">' + '</ons-icon>' +
            '</ons-col>' +

            '<ons-col>' +
            '<div class=desc>'+'<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-soup-can fa-lg" fixed-width="true" icon="ion-soup-can">'+
            '</ons-icon>'
            + data['Details'][i]['varPOBOXAddress']+
            '</div>'+
            '</ons-col>'+
            '</ons-row>'+
             '</ons-list-item>'+
             '</ons-list>'+
             '<div class=caw-botton>'+
             '<ons-row class="row ons-row-inner">'+ 
                '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("book-page.html");>'+
                 '<div style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.6); padding: 12px 0; background: #0ad046; color: #FFF;">'+
                   '<i class="ion-compose">'+'</i>Book Now</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+
               '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("book-page.html");>'+
                   '<div style="padding: 12px 0; background: #cccccc; color: #FFF;">'+
                  '<i class="ion-edit">'+
                  '</i>Write a Review</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+
             '</ons-row>'+
                ' </div>';


                }
            }

//            
//            $scope.call = function (message)
//            {
//                parent.location.href = "tel:{{message.varPhone}}";
//
//            };


            $scope.snippet = Content;

        }).error(function ()
        {
            alert("error");
        });

         $scope.sendEmail = function(email, subject, body){
        var link = "mailto:"+ email
                 + "&subject=New email " + escape(subject);
                 + "&body=" + escape(body); 

        window.location.href = link;
     };

       $scope.openWebsite = function ()
    {
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    };

        $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function ()
        {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
        };
    });
```

now nothing is happening on its click..!!

Comment: I've no idea how you use an intrinsic event attribute (which you should avoid because they are awful and have many gotchas) to call a method on the angular $scope object, but your code is trying to call a global.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_10 — looks like you should be using ng-click, not onclick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This part is problematic (among a few others):

```
onclick=openWebsite(url);
```

You need to use angular's build-it directive `ng-click`

```
<ons-col ng-click="openWebsite(url)">
```

If you use `onclick`, you register a native handler for the `click` event and the browser tries to find the `openWebsite()`  function in the global (window) scope (note: no relation to Angular scopes), where it does not exist.

If you use `ng-click`, on the other hand, Angular will search for the `openWebsite()` method in the corresponding scope, which is what you want.

**Edit:** in case this does not work, please see some of the other answers as well for possible causes (e.g. the Angular app not being bootstrapped properly). I focused on the most apparent (and IMO the most likely cause) of the problem.

**Update:**
With the whole controller posted now, I see the problem. By the time you create that massive HTML snippet on the fly in your controller, Angular has long ago finished processing and bootstrapping everything. This means that when you include the snippet into your page, it *does not get compiled*. Angular does not process the directives such as ng-click in it, does not create scopes, does not create bindings between the scope elements and DOM nodes, etc.

I am afraid you will need to refactor your code quite a lot. That huge HTML snippet should actually be included into your page, there are quite a few possibilities here, for example:

- by using the built-in `ng-include` directive in your "main" template
- by writing your own directive that loads that HTML as its template
- by using the `$compile` service to compile the HTML snippet, so that angular does all those things I mentioned above that it does not when you simply include the HTML as a raw unprocessed string.

Saying what would be the best option for use case and describing it in details is beyond the scope of the initial question and the would require too long or an answer. I would suggest to do some more research on Angular and have a look at some smaller toy applications to get a general idea for the "right" patterns to use.

Comment: hello i have edited my code as per suggest,but now nothing is happening on click.!! :(

Comment: Do you get any helpful error in the console? Have you verified that your application has been correctly bootstrapped, and other things people suggested? Without additional information, it is difficult to tell what the exact problem is, there are multiple possible causes...

Comment: Another guess: you are using a custom tag `<ons-col>`, are you sure the corresponding directive is properly initialized? Or is it supposed to be a `<div>` but your question is misformatted? Please check that, too, and edit the question if needed.

Comment: wait i am posting my whole controller to the question and yes i am getting error "ReferenceError: sendEmail is not defined" in console.pls see my edits

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Maybe not what you have initially expected, but it turned out that a complete solution would be too long to describe. I do hope, though, that it gives you some new useful hints!

Comment: hi.sir when i am using   `'<ons-col class="action-col col ons-col-inner"  ng-click="openWebsite(url)">'+  ` this as per suggested ,nothing is happening on click event,pls note my code is in controller.

Comment: The answer has already been updated based on the controller code that was subsequently provided, it's the part in the `"Update"` section. Is there something missing perhaps? I can update it again and/or rephrase some things that might not be clear enough, if needed.

Comment: but how to change some code in controller and some in html..it fires design issues..:(

Comment: Have you tried going through the [AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) yet? If not, you might find it helpful to get a better understanding of how the code should be separated between controllers, services, HTML templates and other components, and how these various building blocks of an Angular application fit together. I'm sorry if I can't give you a definite and complete answer, but the question on general Angular application design would probably require a whole article or even a tutorial, it's not possible to give that in a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of points to check here with the code provided:

Make sure you have assigned your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to the elements wrapping the element you are calling the function within with the proper controller and module names that defines your `openWebsite`.

As @Quentin stated also `ng-click` is to be used rather than onClick

Your function does not have a parameter but when called :

```
$scope.openWebsite = function (url)
    {
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    };
```

This is not the main cause though but it shall be checked.

Comment: i have changed my code ,pls look in my question as update

Comment: if you wanna use your code this way, no need for ng-click, since your are not using angular scope functions anymore, you can simply use onclick for this case, do not mix things up. `ng-click` is only used with angular scope function events or angular expressions, `onclick` is used to execute native javascript code like calling a function which is the same case as your updated question.

Comment: i am getting "function not defined" though i have function in my controller..! :(

Answer (score 0):

variable is not received in openwebsite(). Write

```
$scope.openWebsite = function (url)
    {
        window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    };
```

And use ng-click="openwebsite(url)" instead of onclick="openwebsite(url)"

Comment: While that is *a* problem, it is not the problem causing the error being asked about.

Comment: i think ng-click has to be used instead of onclick

Comment: @krishna-ng-click is not working,nothing is happening while i am using ng-click instead of onclick ..:(

Answer (score 0):

With Angular, you should use (click)="signUpwithEmail()"

Example,

```
 <ion-button (click)="signUpwithEmail()">
          Sign up with Email
 </ion-button>
```